# set_params() in sklean pipeline not working with TransformTargetRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest

I would like to make a prediction of a single tree of my random forest. However, if I wrap my pipeline around `TransformedTargetRegressor` `.set_params` does not seem to work.

Please find below an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# loading data
boston = load_boston()
X = boston["data"]
Y = boston["target"]

# pipeline and training
pipe = Pipeline([      
                    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                    ('model', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, max_depth = 4, random_state = 0))
                 ])
treg = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipe, transformer=StandardScaler())
treg.fit(X, Y)

# single tree from random forest
tree = treg.regressor_.named_steps['model'].estimators_[0]


x_sample = X[0:1]
print('baseline: ', treg.predict(x_sample))

x_scaled = treg.regressor_.named_steps['scaler'].transform(x_sample)
y_predicted = tree.predict(x_scaled)
y_transformed = treg.transformer_.inverse_transform([y_predicted])
print("internal pipeline changes: ", y_transformed)

new_model = treg.set_params(**{'regressor__model': tree})
y_predicted = new_model.predict(x_sample)
print('with set_params(): ', y_predicted)
```

The output that I am getting is shown below. I would expect 'with set_params()' to be the same like 'internal pipeline changes:

> baseline:  [26.41013313]
>
> internal pipeline changes:  [[30.02424242]]
>
> with set_params():  [26.41013313]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransformedTargetRegressor` has a parameter `regressor` and an attribute `regressor_`.  The former can be set with `set_params` and is considered a hyperparameter, but is not used in prediction; rather, it is cloned and fitted when the TTR is fitted, and stored in the `regressor_` attribute.

So you cannot use `set_params` to update the fitted regressor attribute.  (You can check that in your code, `new_model.regressor_['model']` is still a random forest.)  The best you can do is directly modify the attribute (though this is probably unorthodox, and in some situations may lead to other issues):

```py
import copy
mod_model = copy.deepcopy(treg)
mod_model.regressor_.steps[-1] = ('model', tree)
y_predicted = mod_model.predict(x_sample)
print('with modifying regressor: ', y_predicted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, scikit-learn `TransformedTargetRegressor` objects don't allow you to change the regressor used to predict, **unless you re-fit the dataset on the new regressor in set_params**. If you do this:

```py
new_model = treg.set_params(**{'regressor__model': tree})
print(new_model)
```

you can see that the new parameters have been set. However, as you correctly discovered, the estimator used in `predict` is still the old one. If you want to change the estimator in the object, you can do:

```py
new_model = treg.set_params(**{'regressor__model': tree})
new_model.fit(X, Y)

new_model.predict(x_sample)
```

And you can see that the prediction changes and uses the single tree to perform the estimation. If you are interested in the sinlge tree's prediciton and not re-fit on the whole dataset, you can just call, `tree.predict()` separately.